# Strange Query Performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

We use RedGate's SQL Monitor tool to help identify any issues with our SQL Server and have been receiving notifications every morning about a job which deviates from it's baseline run time (running for roughly 3 minutes instead of 30 seconds).

The job summarises a number of database tables into a (let's call it) cache table and runs every 5 minutes between 7am and 7pm. It therefore seems logical that after the first run at 7am the query plan is optimised/cached and all subsequent executions run more quickly.

To try and avoid these notifications we created a new job which runs just once per day at 7am with exactly the same code as the recurring job. We then moved the recurring job to start at 7.05am.

Bizarrely, the once daily 7am job only takes 30 seconds to execute and yet the first ourrence of the recurring job at 7.05am continues to take 3minutes.

Can anyone explain this?

Is there a more effective solution (saving the execution plan or providing query hints perhaps?).

Comment: Have you tried to capture execution plan of 3 minutes execution time? I know you probably did, but just asking.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas not yet. My only experience with execution plans is within SSMS. Will I have to be in the office and have SQL Profiler running when the jobs execute at 7.00 and 7.05? Or can I enable execution plan logging for jobs somehow? Thanks

Comment: I would personally create a XE Session to capture code and execution plan that's being ran. Read more here: http://jasonbrimhall.info/2015/06/17/execution-plans-in-extended-events/ Of course, you'll have to tweak filters in order to capture code that you're running, but this should be the very first step into debugging. How does that look to you?

Comment: To capture the execution plan using a trace you not necessarily have to use Profiler, you can start and stop a trace using a job. You can even extract the plan not at the 7:00 or 7:05 but later, you can try to extract it even now. The thing you are missing though is that the subsequent job execution can use the same plan, and likely it does.

Comment: @sepupic how do I go about extracting the plan now? I had hoped it would use the same plan- which is exactly why I created the second job... but the timings suggest otherwise. thanks

Comment: You can search for it in the plan cache using smth like this: select *
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
     cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.plan_handle) as t
 where t.text like ...

Comment: There are creation_time, min_elapsed_time, max_elapsed_time fields in sys.dm_exec_query_stats, so you can see when it was created and it it takes 30 seconds and 3 minutes as well

Comment: So i've found two entries running that query. One says starting 07.05 and the other 07.10. Both exactly the same text. One has 122 runs, the other 123. Is that helpful?

Comment: Ooops. I think i've sussed it. The one off job was set to 00:07:00 (i.e. seven minutes past midnight not seven am). I have modified it and will see what happens in the morning. Thanks for your hep!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the PLAN in my query, you can extract it like this: select *
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
     cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.plan_handle) as t
     **cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) as p**
 where t.text like ...'%...'

Comment: It seems like it recompiles every day, is 122/123 the execution count? So it may be the compilation time